# How to change macro value in C file with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like change macro value in C file with **sed**.
For example,

```
#define MY_MACRO VALUE1
```

with

```
#define MY_MACRO VALUE2
```

sed should search for known MY_MACRO name (can be regex) and set new value provided. Old macro value isn't known when calling sed.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any value with `.*`: `.` matches any character, `*` means *repeat zero or more times*.

```
sed 's/#define MY_MACRO .*/#define MY_MACRO VALUE2/'
```

You can make it shorter with a capture group

```
sed 's/\(#define MY_MACRO \).*/\1VALUE2/'
```

If the `#` sign must be at the beginning of a line, you can add the `^` special character that matches at line beginnings:

```
sed 's/^\(#define MY_MACRO \).*/\1VALUE2/'
```

But it can get even more complicated if there's a variable number of spaces between the words etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!